# Find substring in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a data, where there are words in some rows.
For example:

**Test String**

**(Test1) String**

**Test (String1)**

I need to find a substring in brackets using pandas. So, output here will be **['Test1', 'String1']**

I tried something like this, but I can't find a word exactly in brackets.

```
df['column'].str.extract('([A-Z]\w{0,})')
```

Comment: Please post sample data and what you're trying to extract with desired output

Comment: @EdChum I've added sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex pattern:

```
In [180]:
df['text'].str.extract(r'\((\w+)\)')

Out[180]:
0        NaN
1      Test1
2    String1
Name: text, dtype: object
```

So this looks for any words that are present in brackets, here brackets need to be escaped `\(` for example, we also want to find all words so `w+` is needed here.

If you want a list you can call `dropna` and then `tolist`:

```
In [185]:
df['text'].str.extract(r'\((\w+)\)').dropna().tolist()

Out[185]:
['Test1', 'String1']
```